# Magento duplicate the product getting innodb lock timeout error

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database, catalog

My customer doing instant of create a new product they duplicate the product and change the **attributes,inventory,name,sku**,etc to make it a new product.

Since We are facing randomly database innodb error like below

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET
>   entity_type_id = ?, attribute_set_id = ?, type_id = ?, sku = ?,
>   has_options = ?, required_options = ?, created_at = '2015-07-22
>   21:31:59', updated_at = '2016-03-17 14:58:23' WHERE (entity_id=1395)"

This error not happening every time it is happening randomly or some times only. when i get this error after some minutes i will try again with successfully product duplication. I really don't have any idea why its happening.

I have not touch any core functionality yet. I have not installed any extensions related to duplicate or product.

I am nearly struggling more then a week to find the problem. But no luck yet. So please kindly give me your suggestions to fix the issue.

Comment: I have increased **innodb_lock_wait_timeout**  initially the value is 50 after i have changed into 100 again i got a same problem so now i changed 150 but still i getting same error.

Comment: May be it will help you http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/magento-ecommerce/magento-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-1205-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Comment: Try setting your indexing to manual for a bit. Then duplicate. See if problem persist. It may be slow indexing causing the locks. If it does work with indecing set to manual, set each index to update on save. Identify the indexer that is causing the issue. My bet is on url_rewrite indexer.

Comment: @Arunendra Thanks i have checked this article in my search i killed sleeping connection but no luck. Again i am getting this error. I can see again sleeping connections.

Comment: @ProxiBlue Sorry please elaborate to understand more.

Comment: Also i need to know if create a product instant of duplicate a product what are the problems we are going to face. any idea regarding this. I found one duplicate images available in media folder. like any other

Comment: Not sure what you require me to elaborate on. Do you know how to set indexing to manual? This is not a solution, but a fault/cause finding mission. Once you know what is locking the db you can action a solution. Until tgen, you are simply poking at magento with a stick. ☺